# What does [0] * n mean?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I created a matrix, brought it out and then the code according to my question:

```
maxsum = [0] * len(N)
for i in range(a):
    maxsum[i] = sum(N[i])
print(f'максимальная cтрока {maxsum.index(max(maxsum))+1} сумма {max(maxsum)}',
      f'минимальная cтрока {maxsum.index(min(maxsum))+1} сумма {min(maxsum)}',
      sep="\n", end=" ")
```

What does it mean to multiply `[0]` by the length of my matrix and why add 1 in the output?

The code works, I want you to comment, explain this: `maxsum = [0] * len(N)`.

Comment: If the content of the strings is relevant for the question: please translate into English. And please format your questions properly.

Comment: Why are you asking *us* what code means that ***you*** wrote? Did you already forget why you wrote it?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list of only zeroes where the number of elements =
total rows of matrix.

For example, `[0]*5` would give `[0,0,0,0,0]`. Then through loops, you are assigning the sum of ith row to ith index of the list and printing the index of maximum value.

I would say that it's kind of like allocating memory for the sum of all rows in the list

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear explanation